# writing binary data using swift Data (ico format, specifically)

Tags: swift

I am struggling to convert a png image into an [ico image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)), using swift. This is the code I have so far, ish. I'm not sure how to write the correct data that doesn't clearly fit into a byte without manually bit shifting. e.g. Php has a [pack()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function. I don't see anything similar in Swift.

What's the best way to create this file using swift?

```
else if image.type == "image/png" {
    if let i = NSImage(data: imageData), let resized16 = resize(image: i, w: 16, h: 16).png {
        let byteArrayFromData16: [UInt8] = [UInt8](resized16)

        var ico = Data(count: 6)
        //Header
        ico[0] = 0
                        ico[1] = 0
                        ico[2] = 0
                        ico[3] = 1  //1 = ICO or 2 = CUR
                        ico[4] = 0
                        ico[5] = 1 //Number of images in file

                        //ICONDIRENTRY structure
                        var icoImage16 = Data(count: 16)
                        icoImage16[0] = UInt8(16)
                        icoImage16[1] = UInt8(16)
                        icoImage16[2] = 0    //color palate
                        icoImage16[3] = 0 //Reserved
                        icoImage16[4] = 0   // Color planes
                        icoImage16[5] = 0
                        icoImage16[6] = 0   //Bits per pixel
                        icoImage16[7] = 32
                        icoImage16[8] = 0   // size of the image's data in bytes
                        icoImage16[9] = 0
                        icoImage16[10] = 0
                        icoImage16[11] = 0
                        icoImage16[12] = 0 // Offset of png file
                        icoImage16[13] = 0 //
                        icoImage16[14] = 0 //
                        icoImage16[15] = 16 + 6 //

        icoImage16.append(contentsOf: byteArrayFromData16)

        ico.append(contentsOf: icoImage16)
        return ico
    } else {
        error = "Unable to convert selected image \(image.name) to a favicon."
    }
}
```